# Is there any none .NET/CLI based implementation of a C# compiler?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

I just want the ECMA language translated into native code with the fundamental runtime (garbage collector) etc. I'm not talking about .NET just the language specification of C#.

Using C# like any other native compiling language as a langauge alternative for Delphi, D or C++ because it offers generics, expanded types, garbage collection and many other nice features. As a langauge it's pretty nice.

But i don't like .NET nor do i find it very portable (.NET for PA-RISC's HP-UX anyone?).

So a compilation to C99 would be much, much better then compilation to native (that’s how it works very well for Eiffel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the [Salamander .NET Mini-Deployment tool](http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/) may help you, it does convert the code to native and has an embedded runtime, so that you don't need the .NET framework for deployment.

Answer (score 1):

The Mono framework has support for native compilation, which they call Ahead Of Time (AOT) compilation. More here: http://www.mono-project.com/AOT

Comment: Right but this like Bartok does not work without CLI and all this stuff. I just want someone who is implementing the language specification, like Tower Java was doing it a long time ago for Java.

Answer (score 0):

[Singularity RDK](http://singularity.codeplex.com/) uses [Bartok](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartok_(compiler)).  Also the [.Net Micro Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/bb267253.aspx) has several native compilers (last I used the Micro Framework it **did not** have a native x86 compiler).

A third party option would be to use the [Salamander .NET Linker](http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [Native Image Generator (NGEN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx) is capable of converting .NET assemblies into native programs. However, it only means that the JIT compiler is being bypassed, and the .NET Framework is still required to be installed.

> The Native Image Generator (Ngen.exe)
>   is a tool that improves the
>   performance of managed applications.
>   Ngen.exe creates native images, which
>   are files containing compiled
>   processor-specific machine code, and
>   installs them into the native image
>   cache on the local computer. The
>   runtime can use native images from the
>   cache instead of using the
>   just-in-time (JIT) compiler to compile
>   the original assembly.

Perhaps you could elaborate on the context in which you need native code for your .NET assemblies? Depending on the purpose, NGEN may be good enough, though a tool that actually eliminates dependencies on the .NET Framework may be what you want.

Comment: I don't want .NET assemblies compiled. I'm just looking for an language alternative. I like the C# language more then D and for much much more then this braindead C++. But i need an optimizing, static typed, imperative garbage collected language with generics and an implementation which is generating native compiling for very fast startup implementation and execution of this language. I have all this with my hacked Eiffel compiler but i worry about the future and have to port it to another (alive) language sooner and later.

Comment: @Lothar: By all means, it seems like you *are* looking to compile .NET assemblies. Please clarify your question if possible.